# Deleted /default/index.theme

Tags: unity, 14.04, themes, icons, icon-themes

Could anyone who is using the standard Ambiance or Radiance themes and icons, please post me a copy of this file /usr/share/icon/default/index.theme , I overwrote it by  accident and do not have a back up. It would be very much appreciated. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `/usr/share/icons/default/index.theme` is only symbolic link:

```
index.theme -> /etc/alternatives/x-cursor-theme
```

And Further is is linked to `/usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme` as following:

```
x-cursor-theme -> /usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/cursor.theme
```

---

So Source files are found in **`/usr/share/icons/DMZ-White/`** Here is list of themes:-

```
$ ls /usr/share/icons/DMZ-White | grep theme
cursor.theme
index.theme
```

From when you can create link by `ln`.